# Cannot import files between two projects in a workspace xcode7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, workspace

[image]I have a workspace , containing two projects ProjectA and Project 
B , i want to import some files in project A from projectB

`#import "somefileFromProjectB.h"` doesnot work.
It gives error , "file not found" .I have tried many soultions on stackoverflow but they didnot work for me. Can anyone provide solution for this? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using cocoapods?

Comment: have you tried using the file path in your import statement ?

Comment: yes i added file paths to Header Paths , still did not work

Comment: @P.J i tried this also but it didnot work for me.

Comment: @Logic Refer https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: @P.J , i have done this there dependencies error between the projects.pods are working fine.

Comment: @Logic So what is your issue then?

Comment: from the project in bottom i want to import some file  SocketiO.h in  , to LicodeServer.h ,which is in top project it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog helped me to solve the issue , may be it would be helpful for others :http://chadgibbons.com/2012/09/22/project-dependencies-and-include-files-in-xcode/